# Set Timeout With WebClient

Tags: spring-boot, microservices, resttemplate, spring-webclient

```
    @LoadBalanced 
    @Bean 
   public RestTemplate getRestTemplate() 
  {    
     HttpComponentClientHttpRequestFactory clientHttpRequestFactory=
             new HttpComponentClientHttpRequestFactory();
    
             clientHttpRequestFactory.setConnectTimeout(5000);
    
       return new RestTemplate(clientHttpRequestFactory); 
  }
```

I have to replace the above code with WebClient

```
@LoadBalanced
@Bean(name = "WebClient")
public WebClient.Builder getWebClientBuilder()
{
    // create HttpComponentClientHttpRequestFactory instance and it can not be
    //passed to builder method as an argument
    return WebClient.builder();
}
```

I need an alternative to set timeout with WebClient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a timeout for a specific request you can do something like:

```
webClient.get()
        .uri("/employees")
        .retrieve()
        .bodyToFlux(Employee.class)
        .timeout(Duration.ofMillis(10_000))
```

If instead of this you want a timeout to be applied to all the request you can build your web client like this:

```
@Bean
    public WebClient getWebClient()
    {
        HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.create()
                .tcpConfiguration(client ->
                        client.option(ChannelOption.CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS, 10000)
                        .doOnConnected(conn -> conn
                                .addHandlerLast(new ReadTimeoutHandler(10))
                                .addHandlerLast(new WriteTimeoutHandler(10))));
         
        ClientHttpConnector connector = new ReactorClientHttpConnector(httpClient.wiretap(true));       
 
        return WebClient.builder()
                .baseUrl("http://localhost:3000")
                .clientConnector(connector)
                .defaultHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
                .build();
    }
}
```

you can see it here

https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-webflux/webclient-set-timeouts/